# Confidence interval for samples with frequencies

Tags: confidence-interval, sample, t-confidence-interval

I have a total population size of $N$ (known). From the unique elements of the pool I draw samples $s_i, i=1 \ldots m$ without replacement. I also know that each sample $s_i$ appears $k_i$ times in the population pool.

How can I calculate a confidence interval for the mean from this sample that makes use of the frequencies? Is it correct to use the weighted mean and standard deviation with degrees of freedom = $m-1$ (or $\sum_{i=1}^m k_i-1$)? Intuitively I would think that the uncertainty should be greater if $\sum_{i=1}^m k_i <<N$ but $N$ would not be a factor in this approach.

Comment: Can some of the $s_i$ values be repeated in your sample?  If not, how are you sampling from the population?

Comment: How can a sample with $m$ elements appear $k$ times in the population pool?  Wouldn't the different elements of the sample appear different numbers of times in the population?  Also - if you know the frequency of each element in the population, why resort to sampling in the first place?

Comment: Yes, sorry that wasn't clear. Each $s_i$ is different. I'm sampling from the unique elements only. Basically for some other computational resource restrictions.